# Check date unless blank in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In a model I have a query like this to get active projects:

```
self.projects.where('start_date <= ?', Time.now).where('end_date >= ?', Time.now)
```

Now it can be possible to have an empty end_date. How can I make the second where optional so it only applies to filled in end_dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
projects.where(...).where('end_date IS NULL OR end_date >= ?', Time.now)
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Is "IS NULL" specific SQL or general activerecord?

Comment: It's a plain old SQL statement. See ["Working with NULL Values"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) for MySQL version.